# Convert 3 digit input to date format

Tags: sql, oracle

Even though the business requirement states the input as a "julian" date, it is actually a 3 digit number being passed to the Oracle stored procedure. For example, if the input is '001' then I need to convert it to January1 of the current year or if it is 010 convert it to January 10 of the current year etc. How would i do that taking into consideration leap years too?
Please suggest. Thank you for your time.

Comment: how would you represent the 10th of november with three digits?

Comment: Kevin, the input i would get on that is an daily increment from January 01 of the year, which is 001.

Comment: so basicly you pass the day of the year?

Answer (score 3):

if the three digit number represents the day of the year you could simply use the `to_date` function with `DDD`, which represents a three digit number which is the day of the year.

```
select to_char(to_date(310, 'DDD'),'DD.MM.YYYY') from dual; -- 05.11.2016
select to_char(to_date(001, 'DDD'),'DD.MM.YYYY') from dual; -- 01.01.2016
select to_char(to_date(010, 'DDD'),'DD.MM.YYYY') from dual; -- 10.01.2016
select to_char(to_date(060, 'DDD'),'DD.MM.YYYY') from dual; -- 29.02.2016
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this approach.

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'YY') + 060 - 1, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as day from dual;
```

29/02/2016

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'YY') + 010 - 1, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as day from dual;
```

10/01/2016